# What is that weird sticky stuff in tea?

Tags: single-word-requests

Whenever I am having tea, there is always this layer of a substance that is darker than the tea itself on top of the tea's surface and I can use my finger to skim it off the surface. It is kind of like a solid like. What is this thing called?

Comment: I'd call it a [floc](https://www.yourdictionary.com/floc). It is a scum of calcium carbonate and lots of organics that are attracted to calcium carbonate. [Probably more than you wanted to know](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2005/nov/04/foodanddrink.features)

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful

Comment: You obviously only drink dark Indian style tea. Floc (thank you @PhilSweet) does not seem to form on green 'china' tea. Also the acid in milk and in lemon juice disperses it (although it does often reappear on cold tea with milk in it)

Comment: I drink tea from the brand Red Label @BoldBen , not sure if that is Indian style tea or not. Also, I do drink tea with milk so that it has a light-brown color always, but it keeps showing up.

Comment: Actually you are right, I looked it up and it is Indian tea

Comment: I would call it a “skin”, but I’m not sure how common that is.

Comment: Probably off-topic. Definitely off-putting.